# MacroPy installation fails

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew, macropy

Trying to install MacroPy with `pip` on Python 3.4.3, but I get an arror:

```
$ pip3 install MacroPy

Collecting MacroPy
  Downloading MacroPy-1.0.3.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/hq/r_l8wk257_71w4rtrkj5b7d80000gn/T/pip-build-10_id3bj/MacroPy/setup.py", line 62, in <module>
        from macropy import __version__
      File "/private/var/folders/hq/r_l8wk257_71w4rtrkj5b7d80000gn/T/pip-build-10_id3bj/MacroPy/macropy/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
        import core.exporters
    ImportError: No module named 'core'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/hq/r_l8wk257_71w4rtrkj5b7d80000gn/T/pip-build-10_id3bj/MacroPy
```

System is OSX 10.10.3, with Python from HomeBrew.

Edit: installation on Python 2.x works fine.

Comment: I get the same error, I think their setup.py might be misconfigured for python3.

Comment: ah, indeed: I installed the same MacroPy successfully on Python 2

Answer (score 2):

MacroPy currently doesn't support Python 3. As for now, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy/issues/32) on porting macropy to Python 3, where possible approaches and partial solutions are discussed. However, it doesn't work now out of the box and looks more or less abandoned.